# Discrete Cosine Transformation 1D Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, image-compression, dct

I'm trying to implement DCT in MATLAB by using matrix-vector multiplication.  Specifically, I'd like to create the DCT matrix of coefficients then use this to multiply with 1D signal to compute the 1D DCT.

Here's my code to produce the DCT matrix:

```
function D=dct1d(n)
for u=0:n-1
   if u==0
       au=sqrt(1/n);
   else
       au=sqrt(2/n);
    end
   for x=0:n-1
       D(u+1,x+1)=au*cos(((2*x+1)*u*pi)/2*n); 
   end
end
```

After this I tried performing the DCT with a test signal of `x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`:

```
x=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
y=dct1(8)*x';
```

The answer it gives is:

```
12.7279
18.0000
18.0000
18.0000
18.0000
18.0000
18.0000
18.0000
```

However, the correct answer is:

```
12.7279
-6.4423
-0.0000
-0.6735
      0
-0.2009
-0.0000
-0.0507
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in your code is very slight but fundamental. The line where you're computing the coefficients:

```
D(u+1,x+1)=au*cos(((2*x+1)*u*pi)/2*n);
```

Take a look at the very last part of the line:

```
D(u+1,x+1)=au*cos(((2*x+1)*u*pi)/2*n);
%//                              ^^^
```

[Because multiplication and division are equal in precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html), this is exactly the same as doing:

```
D(u+1,x+1)=au*cos((((2*x+1)*u*pi)/2)*n);
```

As such, you aren't dividing by `2n`.  You are dividing by 2 then **multiplying by `n`** which is incorrect.  You simply have to surround the `2*n` operation with brackets:

```
D(u+1,x+1)=au*cos(((2*x+1)*u*pi)/(2*n));
```

Once you do this, we get the correct DCT matrix.  BTW, one way to check if you have the right answer is to use the [`dctmtx`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dctmtx.html) function, which calculates the `N x N` DCT coefficient matrix that you're seeking.  However, this function is part of the Signal Processing Toolbox, so if you don't have that then you unfortunately can't use this function, but if I can suggest an alternative answer instead of using `for` loops, I would build a 2D grid of coordinates with [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), then compute element-wise products.

Something like this would work instead:

```
function D = dct1d(n)

[x,u] = meshgrid(0:n-1);
D = sqrt(2/n)*cos(((2*x+1).*u*pi)/(2*n)); 
D(1,:) = D(1,:) / sqrt(2);

end
```

Instead of using an `if` statement to determine what weights we need to apply per row, we can just use `sqrt(2/n)` then divide by `sqrt(2)` for the first row so that you're dividing by `sqrt(1/n)` instead.  This code should produce the same results as your corrected code<sup>1</sup>.

---

In any case, once I made these corrections, I compared both of the answers between what your code gives and what `dctmtx` gives and it's right:

```
>> dct1d(8)

ans =

    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536
    0.4904    0.4157    0.2778    0.0975   -0.0975   -0.2778   -0.4157   -0.4904
    0.4619    0.1913   -0.1913   -0.4619   -0.4619   -0.1913    0.1913    0.4619
    0.4157   -0.0975   -0.4904   -0.2778    0.2778    0.4904    0.0975   -0.4157
    0.3536   -0.3536   -0.3536    0.3536    0.3536   -0.3536   -0.3536    0.3536
    0.2778   -0.4904    0.0975    0.4157   -0.4157   -0.0975    0.4904   -0.2778
    0.1913   -0.4619    0.4619   -0.1913   -0.1913    0.4619   -0.4619    0.1913
    0.0975   -0.2778    0.4157   -0.4904    0.4904   -0.4157    0.2778   -0.0975

>> dctmtx(8)

ans =

    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536
    0.4904    0.4157    0.2778    0.0975   -0.0975   -0.2778   -0.4157   -0.4904
    0.4619    0.1913   -0.1913   -0.4619   -0.4619   -0.1913    0.1913    0.4619
    0.4157   -0.0975   -0.4904   -0.2778    0.2778    0.4904    0.0975   -0.4157
    0.3536   -0.3536   -0.3536    0.3536    0.3536   -0.3536   -0.3536    0.3536
    0.2778   -0.4904    0.0975    0.4157   -0.4157   -0.0975    0.4904   -0.2778
    0.1913   -0.4619    0.4619   -0.1913   -0.1913    0.4619   -0.4619    0.1913
    0.0975   -0.2778    0.4157   -0.4904    0.4904   -0.4157    0.2778   -0.0975
```

Once we get the corrected DCT matrix, we can check the actual DCT calculations by performing the matrix multiplication with the test vector of `1:8` that you used:

```
>> dct1d(8)*((1:8).')

ans =

   12.7279
   -6.4423
   -0.0000
   -0.6735
         0
   -0.2009
   -0.0000
   -0.0507
```

---

<sup>1. This code is actually what is being done in `dctmtx` under the hood, once you strip away all of the error checking and input consistency checks.</sup>

Comment: Thnx I forgot about the precedence

Comment: @MarkBen I've also created a more efficient version of `dct1d` for you.  I prefer to do it this way with vectorized operations, but whatever you need to understand how it works!